# String index out of range error in java method

Tags: java, eclipse

I am creating an engine for chess board game in java, and i want to create a method that counts the number of items left for each player here is my code:

```
public class ChessBoard
{
    private boolean belongsToPlayer(char piece, int player)
    {
        if (player == 0 && Character.isUpperCase(piece))
            return true;
        if (player == 1 && Character.isLowerCase(piece))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    final public int getCount(final String[] board, final int player) {
        int count = 0;
        int size = board.length;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < size; j++) {
                if (belongsToPlayer(board[i].charAt(j), player)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

but the problem is that i am getting String index out of range @ `if (belongsToPlayer(board[i].charAt(j), player))`
anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: And how long are the strings in `board`?

Answer (score 1):

The length of `board[i]` is apparently shorter than `size`.  If your intent is to loop through each character of the string, change your loop to this:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length(); j++) {
            if (belongsToPlayer(board[i].charAt(j), player)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if (belongsToPlayer(board[i].charAt(j), player))
```

means that the words in `board` have the same length as the size of `board`. If the words are actually smaller, you gonna try to reach an unavailable index in the word with `charAt`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is zero-indexed, so the first element in an array (and the first character in a String) has the index 0, not 1. Iterate from 0 to length - 1.

You're also iterating over a String between 1 (see above for why this is incorrect) and your `size` variable, which is the length of the `board` array. Unless they're the same length in all cases, you're likely to run into index issues from this as well.

Comment: That's true, and it's *a* problem with the code, but note that the for-loop conditional is `j < size`, not `j <= size`, so I don't think it's *the* problem with the code.

Comment: While true, this wouldn't cause the error as he is looping from 1 to length-1 (essentially skipping the first character).

Comment: @JamesMontagne The code loops from 1, not 0, in both cases, and there's no subtraction of 1 from the length variable - it looks like a classic problem of not knowing that indexes start at 0 to me. And even if he does want to skip the first character (or String, in the outer loop), there's no error checking to ensure that the String has at least two characters before doing so.

Comment: As mentioned by @ruakh you don't need to subtract 1 if you're using `<`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I must be tired, I didn't even make the connection between the two. That clears that up.

Answer (score 0):

I think your j loop is incorrect

```
for(int j = 1; j < board[i].length(); j++){
```

Comment: `String.length` is a method, you need the `()`.